# I get a 'Error in Google Request' (400) error using spreadsheet API for some rows, but not for most

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I have a webpage that posts requests to update a Google spreadsheet cell to a php script. It is using the asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client/ PHP wrapper for the Google Spreadsheet API. Most of the time, it works fine. For a few cells, though, it gives me an 'Error in Google Request' error. I investigated and found that the http_code being returned is 400.

I can't figure out what could be different about the cells where update doesn't work. They hold free-form text entered through a Google form, but the cells that have problems are not the ones with the longest text, and there aren't any strange characters. There are more than 100 rows, and I've only found a few where I get this problem, and so far I've only seen the problem with cells in one column, so I'm pretty sure the credentials are ok.

The error comes from the function:

```
function updateCell($row, $col, $val) {
    global $cellFeed;
    try {
        $cellFeed->editCell($row+2, $col+1, $val);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        output('ERROR (updateCell): ' . $e->getMessage());
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and the `$cellFeed` comes from

```
$serviceRequest = new Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);
Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);
$spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
$spreadsheet = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetById($SPREADSHEET_ID);
$worksheetFeed = $spreadsheet->getWorksheets();
$worksheet = $worksheetFeed->getByTitle($WORKSHEET_NAME);
$cellFeed = $worksheet->getCellFeed();
```

Comment: Does the particular column that you mentioned, fall out of range by any chance? I see that you are doing, `$col+1` when you're calling `editCell` so I am curious whether the range might be undefined.

Comment: No, the column index is incremented by 1 because the Google Spreadsheet API uses a 1-based number scheme and the Visualization API (which I use to display the data) is 0-based. Also, the visualization counts the header row, while the Spreadsheet API does not, so the row gets incremented by 2. Updating that column in other rows works fine; it's just a few rows where I get this error.

Comment: Works fine for me. Could it be a data volume problem? I use the batch update. Also I do have an auto retry setup as sometimes it fails.

Comment: It only ever updates one cell at a time, so I don't think it is an issue with data volume. So far I've only found it in this one column, and there are other similar columns that update fine (as do most of the rows, even for this column). Sometimes the text in the cell can be pretty long, but there are cells with more text that update fine. Having a retry is a good idea, but so far it seems that for rows that fail, it always fails.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same error, when there were double quotes in the cell value.
It was fixed by replacing them by &qout;.

It happens becuse of this code in CellFeed.php:

```
public function editCell($rowNum, $colNum, $value)
{
    $entry = sprintf('
        <entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gs="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006">
          <gs:cell row="%u" col="%u" inputValue="%s"/>
        </entry>',
        $rowNum,
        $colNum,
        $value
    );

    ServiceRequestFactory::getInstance()->post($this->getPostUrl(), $entry);
}
```

As you can see, there's no transformation of $value there, so when there are double quotes XML tag become corrupted like:

```
<gs:cell row="%u" col="%u" inputValue="my value with "quotes" in it."/>
```

Comment: Good answer. Doesn't fix my problem, as it occurs whether or not there are any quote marks, but that could be an issue so I am adopting your fix. Thanks

Comment: Well, there can be not only quotes, but some other html characters that should be converted to codes. Do you have examples of "problem strings"?